# EXTjs: Cartesian Chart min column width

Tags: c#, extjs

I use a dynamic cartesianchart, but when the columns are too many its resize them to fit the chart. But I want the columns to have a minimum column width, otherwise the chart is not readable. The page has 2 panels, in the top one there is the CartesianChart and a PolarChart. I follow this [example](http://examples.ext.net/#/Chart/Combination/Dashboard/)

Code:

```
<ext:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="250" MarginSpec="0 0 3 0">
                            <LayoutConfig>
                                <ext:HBoxLayoutConfig Align="Stretch" />
                            </LayoutConfig>
                            <Items>
                                <ext:CartesianChart
                                    ID="BarChart1"
                                    runat="server"
                                    Border="true"
                                    Flex="4"
                                    StoreID="storeSites" AutoScroll="true" Resizable="true" >
                                    <Interactions>
                                        <ext:ItemHighlightInteraction />
                                    </Interactions>
                                    <AnimationConfig Duration="300" Easing="EaseOut" />
                                    <Axes>
                                        <ext:NumericAxis Position="Left" Fields="patientstarget" Minimum="0" Hidden="true" />
                                        <ext:CategoryAxis Position="Bottom" Fields="site">
                                            <Label Font="9px Arial" RotationDegrees="-45" />
                                            <Renderer Handler="return Ext.String.ellipsis(label, 15, false);" />
                                        </ext:CategoryAxis>
                                    </Axes>

                                    <Series>
                                        <ext:BarSeries
                                            Highlight="true"
                                            XField="site"
                                            YField="patientstarget" >
                                            <StyleSpec>
                                                <ext:Sprite FillStyle="#456d9f" />
                                            </StyleSpec>
                                            <HighlightConfig>
                                                <ext:Sprite FillStyle="#619fff" StrokeStyle="black" />
                                            </HighlightConfig>
                                            <Label
                                                Display="InsideEnd"
                                                Field="patientstarget"
                                                Color="#000"
                                                Orientation="Vertical"
                                                TextAlign="Center"
                                                />
                                            <Listeners>
                                                <ItemMouseUp Fn="onMouseUp" />
                                            </Listeners>
                                        </ext:BarSeries>
                                    </Series>
                                    <Plugins>
                                        <ext:ChartItemEvents ID="ChartItemEvents1" runat="server" />
                                    </Plugins>
                                </ext:CartesianChart>

                                //PolarChart
                            </Items>
                        </ext:Panel>
```

Comment: `columnWidth : Number` is a config which you can use for column width. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.chart.CartesianChart.html

Comment: @UDID its not working

Comment: Can you please show some code or can create fiddle which help us to understand.